# Cannot find module 'crawler'

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, visual-studio-code

After installing [node-crawler](https://github.com/bda-research/node-crawler#node-crawler) in Node.js (not in the default directory) via the npm command, I tried to run the code in the "[Usage](https://github.com/bda-research/node-crawler#usage)" section but an error occurs when executing `var Crawler = require("crawler");` and the VisualStudio Code debug console says `Cannot find module 'crawler'`. 
Does it happen because I installed `crawler` in a custom location? How can I fix this?

Comment: Does node complain, or just your IDE?

Comment: You can install it globally and it should be available.

Comment: What do you mean not in the default directory , can you be more precise?

Comment: I installed it globally but not in the C:\Users\USER NAME\AppData\Roaming path (where Node.js usually installs new packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I found the solution. I replaced `"crawler"` in `var Crawler = require("crawler");` with the path that points to the `crawler.js` file in the `lib` folder in `node-modules`, and now the code works. Maybe it happened because I installed `crawler` in a custom location and so VisualStudio couldn't find `"crawler"`.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` will install a package locally. (`--save` to have package appear in your dependencies.)
To have access to it from everywhere, you need to install it globally, using `npm install -g`

Comment: I had already installed the package globally and also locally, but the code doesn't work the same.